# Как выполнить код после загрузки и отображения usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, usercontrol

На форме есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую отображается `usercontrol`. Если в метод `click` кнопки поместить процедуру, то она будет выполняться, затем выход из метода `click` и только тогда появляется `usercontrol`.

А как сделать чтобы сначала показался usercontrol, а затем начал выполняться код процедуры?

Answer (score 3):

Код нужно поместить в следующую процедуру в самой форме:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
        MsgBox "Run after activation (show) of form "
End Sub
```

Если вы не хотите чтобы процедура была внутри класса контроля, то создайте процедуру общего доступа (Public) в любом модуле и тоже вызывайте ее из процедуры активации UserForm_Acivate.

.. В модуле:

```
Public Sub DoSomethingAfterControlShow()
  MsgBox "Ok After show"
End Sub
```

.. В UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  DoSomethingAfterControlShow
End Sub
```

Comment: Мне нужно показать Usercontrol по нажатию кнопки, а после этого запустить код процедуры. Причем здесь событие 'Activate' основной формы. А у 'Usercontrol'нет события 'Activate'.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю суть вопроса, то код

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
   MsgBox("Hi")
   btnUnvisible.Visible = True
End Sub
```

выполняется синхронно и контрол btnUnvisible появляется только после нажатия на кнопку "Ок" диалогового окна. Для того, чтобы любой код (в моем случае это msgbox, но может быть вызов любой другой процедуры) выполнялся асинхронно, нужно переписать обработчик события следующим образом:

```
Private Async Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
   Dim t = New Task(Sub()
                        MsgBox("Hi")
                        ' здесь может быть вызов процедуры или любой другой код 
                    End Sub)
   t.Start()
   btnUnvisible.Visible = True
   Await t
End Sub
```

В данном случае код внутри Task будет выполнен асинхронно (в другом потоке или в этом же, в зависимости от более оптимального расклада с точки зрения пула потоков), весь код между объявлением объекта Task и ожиданием завершения асинхронной процедуры Await t будет выполнен "параллельно" - таким образом, при нажатии на кнопку будет одновременно отображен другой контрол и показано диалоговое окно